# high charts consuming high CPU

Tags: jquery, highcharts, setinterval

We are using jquery ajax call to render highcharts as im using setInterval to render dynamic graph for every 1 minute my cpu memory is consuming more almost its reaching to 100% and im getting kill pages in chrome can you help me how to resolve it

function DataSiftGraph(){

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "ViewGraphServlet",
            type: 'POST',   
            data:{"flag":true,"hrefValue":searchKeyGraph},
            contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",       
            success: function (response) {
                                    tweets=response.tweets;
                                    for(var i=0;i<tweets.length;i++){

                                        descArray[i]=tweets[i];
                                        //alert(descArray[i]);
                                          document.getElementById("detailedcs").innerHTML+= descArray[i]+'<br/>';
                                    }

                                    stopFlag=response.stopFlag;

                                    //series.data.push(formattedTime,response.positiveCount);
                                    //chart.series[0].data.push(formattedTime,response.positiveCount);


                                    shift = chartSentiment.series[0].data.length > 20;

                                    chartSentiment.series[0].addPoint([response.toDate,response.positiveCount],true,shift);
                                    chartSentiment.series[1].addPoint([response.toDate,response.negativeCount],true,shift);
                                    chartSentiment.series[2].addPoint([response.toDate,response.neutralCount],true,shift);

                                    //alert("response.affectionCount" + response.affectionCount);
                                    chartEmotion.series[0].addPoint([response.toDate,response.affectionCount],true,shift);
                                    chartEmotion.series[1].addPoint([response.toDate,response.amusementCount],true,shift);
                                    chartEmotion.series[2].addPoint([response.toDate,response.contentCount],true,shift);
                                    chartEmotion.series[3].addPoint([response.toDate,response.enjoymentCount],true,shift);
                                    chartEmotion.series[4].addPoint([response.toDate,response.angerCount],true,shift);
                                    chartEmotion.series[5].addPoint([response.toDate,response.fearCount],true,shift);
                                    chartEmotion.series[6].addPoint([response.toDate,response.humiliationCount],true,shift);
                                    chartEmotion.series[7].addPoint([response.toDate,response.sadnessCount],true,shift);


                            },
            error:   function(response, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
              }
        });

    }
```

this is the sample code im using

Comment: Can you show a sample of your code ?

Comment: provide more information

Comment: First, check for silly mistakes. That is, check that you are not adding more and more event listeners. Also, it's quite easy to leak memory with closures. However, that is impossible to detect with the code example above. To see that one would need to look at the entire code chain that is executed by setInterval(...).

Answer (score 0):

Which version of highcharts do you use? In case when you use addPoint, in each call function, entire chart is redrawn, so performance dicrease. I advice to set redraw as false (paratmetr in addPoint function) and then redraw after add all points.